# How to access file and directories in Linux machine using java program

Tags: java, linux, sockets, jakarta-ee

I have assignment to access file system using java program. In that , I  want to create file, read file modify file etc (all operation we can do on file and directory as well).

Is there any way we can do using java program / or any api available to do these operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). They don't care about which `OS (Operating System)` are you using. Also `File` wraps files and folders, check the methods [`File.isDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) and [`File.isFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()).

**NOTE**: use also `File.separator` to standarize and avoid problems between `OS`